# Cannot find module /build at sveltekit running on pm2 node server

Tags: node.js, sveltekit, pm2, sveltekit-adapter-node

I want to deploy my sveltekit application on my server using node & pm2. So far, I've followed the tutorial and it lools in my pm2 I have uptime, but I can't navigate to my site.

I used the node adaptar with this small spec:

```
import { vitePreprocess } from "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte";
// import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
import adapter from "@sveltejs/adapter-node";

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
  kit: {
      adapter: adapter({
      out: "build"
    }),
  },
};

export default {
  preprocess: [vitePreprocess({})],
  config,
};
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "bap24",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite dev",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "start": "node build",
    "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./jsconfig.json",
    "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./jsconfig.json --watch"
  },
```

And this is the error-log

```
 Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/bap24/public_html/build'
1|bap24    |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:15)
1|bap24    |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:873:27)
1|bap24    |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
1|bap24    |     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47 {
1|bap24    |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
1|bap24    |   requireStack: []
1|bap24    | }
1|bap24    | node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031
1|bap24    |   throw err;
1|bap24    |   ^
```

My public_html

```
-rw-r--r--   1 bap24 bap24    614 Dec 27 18:46 ecosystem.config.cjs
drwxr-xr-x 215 bap24 bap24  12288 Dec 27 19:49 node_modules
drwxr-xr-x   4 bap24 bap24   4096 Dec 27 18:00 output
-rw-r--r--   1 bap24 bap24   1317 Dec 27 19:38 package.json
-rw-r--r--   1 bap24 bap24 122663 Dec 27 19:49 package-lock.json
```